# Updating an item in an array updates them all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm working on an application using vuejs with vuex which uses projects, with each project having one or more jobs.

I can add, delete and update the jobs. The adding and deleting is working perfect, but the updating is not.

The state in the vuex dev tools:

[image: projects]

My HTML:

```
<div class="job-compact row" v-for="(job, index) in project.jobs">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error' : errors.has('jobs.' + index + '.function')}">
                <input type="text" name="jobs[function][]" class="form-control" v-model="job.function" @change="updateJobValue(index, 'function', $event.target.value)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error' : errors.has('jobs.' + index + '.profiles')}">
                <input type="number" name="jobs[profiles][]" class="form-control" v-model="job.profiles" @change="updateJobValue(index, 'profiles', $event.target.value)"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button v-if="index == 0" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="addJob"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            <button v-if="index > 0" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="deleteJob(index);"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I have a `v-for` that is showing all my jobs. When editing a value inside my jobs, I use the `@change` event to update my value. And, at the bottom, I have two buttons to add and remove a job row.

[image]

My stores are divided into modules. The main store looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {};

const getters = {};

const mutations = {};

const actions = {};

//Separate Module States
import jobCreator from './modules/job-creator/store';

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        jobCreator: jobCreator
    },
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
});
```

The module store for this specific problem:

```
import store from './../../store'

const state = {
    project: {
        title: null,
        description: null,
        jobs: []
    },
    defaultJob: {
        function: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        profiles: 1,
        location_id: '',
        category_id: '',
        budget: '',
    },
};

const getters = {}

const mutations = {

    addJob(state, job) {
        state.project.jobs.push(job);
    },
    deleteJob(state, index) {
        state.project.jobs.splice(index, 1);
    },
    updateJobValue(state, params) {
        Object.assign(state.project.jobs[params.jobIndex], {
            [params.field]: params.value
        });
    }
};

const actions = {
    addJob: function (context) {
        context.commit('addJob', state.defaultJob);
    },
    deleteJob: function (context, index) {
        context.commit('deleteJob', index);
    },
    updateJobValue: function (context, params) {
        context.commit('updateJobValue', params);
    },
};

const module = {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
};

export default module;
```

The project state is mapped to a computed property of my vue instance:

```
computed: {
       ...mapState({
           project: state => state.jobCreator.project,
       }),
}
```

The problem is the following: In the image of the application, you can see that I entered "vin" in one of the fields, but all of the fields are updating.

[image]

So, all of the `function` fields of **all** the jobs have been updated to my last entry, instead of only the one I want.

What am I doing wrong?

PS:

I also tried the following in my mutation function:

```
updateJobValue(state, params) {
    var job = state.project.jobs[params.jobIndex];
    job[params.field] = params.value;

    Vue.set(state.project.jobs, params.jobIndex, job);
}
```

But it's giving me the same result.

UPDATE: As requested, I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7waqoLxn/24/) to show my problem

Comment: Could you possibly turn this into a jsfiddle? Since it is a rather long question it will be much easier for people to help you out that way.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle explaining my problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is in your `addJob` action:

```
addJob: function (context) {
    context.commit('addJob', state.defaultJob);
},
```

You are referencing the `state.defaultJob` object each time you add a new job. That means each item in the `state.project.jobs` array is referencing the same object.

You should create a copy of the object when passing it to the `addJob` mutation:

```
addJob: function (context) {
    context.commit('addJob', Object.assign({}, state.defaultJob));
},
```

Or, just pass in a new object with the default properties each time:

```
addJob: function (context) {
    context.commit('addJob', {
        function: '',
        title: '',
        description: '',
        profiles: 1,
        location_id: '',
        category_id: '',
        budget: '',
    });
},
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/uarvorbj/)

Here's a post explaining how variables are passed in Javascript: [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

I would give the following advice:

Use `v-bind:value="job.function` instead of `v-model="job.function"` because you want only a one way binding. This your code more predictable.

Add a `v-key="job"` to your  `v-for="(job, index) in project.jobs"` element just to be sure that the rendering works correctly.

The first two lines should be enought, the object is still reactive.

```
var job = state.project.jobs[params.jobIndex];
job[params.field] = params.value;


Vue.set(state.project.jobs, params.jobIndex, job);
```

PS: In my fiddle the `@change` did only fire when i hit enter or left the input.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle explaining my problem

Comment: Your problem is in the line `context.commit('addJob', state.defaultJob);`
your adding/referencing the same object all the time. Just change it to `context.commit('addJob', Vue.extend({},state.defaultJob))` and then your will get a new object for each line.